# Запрет CORS на запрос к 300.ya.ru

Tags: javascript, https, cors

У сервиса https://300.ya.ru/ есть API для получения ссылок на пересказ. Там пример написан на Python, вроде, но я написал Fetch запрос к API через JavaScript.

Дело в том, что этот код работает на сайте 300.ya.ru и я получаю в Консоль данные, но, если я запускаю этот код у себя в проекте, то у меня возникает ошибка. Вы можете самостоятельно проверить данный код, у себя, сгенерировав одним нажатием себе ключ, он бесплатен и генерируется сразу. Буду признателен за помощь.

> Access to fetch at 'https://300.ya.ru/api/sharing-url' from origin
> 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```js
const endpoint = "https://300.ya.ru/api/sharing-url";
const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "OAuth <Здесь мой ключ, но в целях безопасности, я его вставлять не буду>",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        article_url: "https://habr.com/ru/news/729422/",
    }),
});

const data = await response.json();
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что этот запрос надо делать на стороне сервера.  А на клиенте увы только дёргать серверную сторону, но  свою

Comment: CORS сделаны специально для того, чтобы скрипт с одного сайта не мог получить доступ к содержимому другого сайта.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский через Node JS?

Comment: Серверный язык может быть любым.